Declarations of fixed payload in proxy server using spring cloud gateway
I am using proxy gateway for the api in spring cloud gateway and for one of request I want to pass a payload without taking it from user and a fix payload should be passed
E.g
{ "Fname": "abc",
"Lname": "xyz"
}
And i am using proxy gateway through application.yaml
spring:

  cloud:

    gateway:

      routes:

        - id: example_route

          uri: http://example.com

          predicates:

            - Path=/example/**

          filters:

            - RewritePath=/example/(?

Can someone help how to do it


Write a custom filter to set the fixed payload before sending to the target URI:

public class FixedPayloadGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<FixedPayloadGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            String payload = "{\"Fname\": \"abc\", \"Lname\": \"xyz\"}";

            // Modify the request with the fixed payload
            ServerHttpRequest modifiedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(payload.length()))
                    .body(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .build();

            // Create a new exchange object with the modified request
            ServerWebExchange modifiedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(modifiedRequest).build();

            return chain.filter(modifiedExchange);
        };
    }
}


Add this custom filter to your routes in application.yaml:

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: example_route
          uri: http://example.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/example/**
          filters:
            - name: FixedPayload

Reference: Creating a custom Spring Cloud Gateway Filter
